# What object is most appropriate for an approval process requested by a customer?

Tags: case, opportunity, approval-process

Assuming there is a customer request that requires approval from the organization, what object between opportunity and case makes the most sense in general or in the following scenario?

**Customer**: Student

**Organization**: University

**Request**: A leave of absence / suspension of studies (with approval or rejection by a registrar)

---

From our initial findings on the above scenario, a case object appears appropriate since it's a customer request awaiting a status. However, an opportunity object also seems appropriate because the request marks potential for revenue loss. Should it be one or the other or should it be both?

Answer (score 1):

This is really an idiosyncratic question, that is open to various opinions. But I'll give it a shot. Note that both objects accept approval processes.

Here are a few characteristics of each object. This list is neither exhaustive nor is meant to tackle all use cases.

**Case**

Cases are normally well suited for interactions between Customers (let's call them external users) and members of the organization that uses CRM. There are many use-cases that don't fit my general rule above, but you get the idea. Think "I need to do X and I need assistance from You".

- They very often are initiated from the "External" side (An internal person can create the actual record but the action that requires a case to be opened is on the external side)
- You can create them via email (using Email 2 Case)
- You can create assignment rules to send them to the right department
- You can easily make them available in a community.

**Opportunity**

Opportunities are better suited for sales (or similar) processes, where you're taking a record through certain steps, until this record is "Won" or "Lost".

- Opportunities are usually stared internally (think about you starting a sale, or recording the possibility of such)
- Opportunities have stages that the record has to go through
- Opportunities are relevant to forecasts and goals
- Opportunities can have a pricelist, and have products associated to it.

**Summary**

Based on the description of your needs, I would use Case. It feels like it better fits the scenario you described, where users make a request and communicate with you about it.